# Single code base multiple platform builds - a feature matrix

Tags: react-native, flutter, xamarin, nativescript

I have project that will have multiple clients: web, Android, iOS and probably a desktop version too.

As I see a few technologies that claim to help me with this like Flutter, React Native, Native Script, Xamarin(?) and others, I do not know which ones might fit (and of course I do not want to study all of them only to find, in the end, that something I wanted is missing).

[*As I do not want this to be tagged as a "opinion-based" question I selected a few specific questions that should give an objective information on each technology someone might mention - more or less similar to a feature matrix*]

Here are a few questions that a technology / framework should pass in order to be a good pick

1. Can I write a single code and then have builds for separate platforms? Or to what degree can I do that? Does it look decent (native) enough on a specific platform?
2. What additional installations do I need in order to obtain a build for a platform? (Ex: Do I need to install Expo Client for React Native in order to be able to run the app on device?)
3. How easy is to access the native API in case I need it? (Run it in background, battery level, screen brightness, services, file system access, etc.)
4. Can I write also server side code with it? To what degree? (Ex: Can I put Dart on server side?)
5. What is the level of support from industry and dev community on it? (Is it backed more by a company or community?)
6. Please mention any other platform that I might not mentioned and you have experience and can fulfill the requirements.

Comment: One missing and well-used cross-platform technology is `ionic`

Comment: All the things you mentioned are front-end frmaeworks. WHy would you want to use these for a backend sevice?

Comment: @Sisir Well, some of those frameworks can use the same back-end language (ex: JavaScript  from NodeJS for React) which might be a plus.